# Ethernet/Broadband Internet on Ubuntu (12.04.3 LTS) ?

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired

How can I connect to the Internet in Ubuntu by 
Ethernet/Broadband cable ?

I need to log in with username and password, but
I don't know what to do.
Can someone tell me which steps should I take?

Comment: Have you tried plugging Ethernet cable into the computer and see if Internet is working or not ?

Comment: @RanaMuhammadWaqas He need to setup DSL type my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the DSL Connection where you can set username and password to login.

Open Network connections and then choose Edit Connections.

Then choose Add and choose DSL Connection. There give your username and password.I am giving you some images so that you can have some idea about what you have to do ( I have taken these in my Xubuntu)

[image]
[image]
[image]